# SpringSecurity - Need to generate a new sessionId on each attempted login

Tags: java, session, spring-security, httprequest, httpsession

I have an application which uses SpringSecurity. My problem arrives if I try to login, it fails, and I attempt again. What happens is that the sessionid is still the same, and this creates problems. I have tried to run:

```
request.getSession(false).invalidate()
final HttpSession session = request.getSession(true)
```

When I do this I get serverError when I try to login, which isn't logged anywhere (I suspect SpringSecurity is to blame...). Is there anyway to force a new session on each login request when using SpringSecurity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably get NullPointerExceptions with

```
request.getSession(false).invalidate();
```

because getSession returns null when there is no session. So this will probably work if you do a null check before doing the invalidate.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session != null) {
    session.invalidate();
}
```